# Installation of vs 2019 community stuck at 98%

Tags: visual-studio, installation

Visual Studio Community 2019
Downloaded
100%

Installing: package 315 of 317
98%

Microsoft.VisualCpp.ASAN.X86

Can someone help?  It is a brand new computer.  AMD Ryzen 5 1600 processor, 8 GB ram

Comment: This has happened to me, on occasions. Just wait a *very* long time - for example, maybe go home and come back tomorrow, if the PC is at work; or, if it's at home, go down the local club for a few hours.

Comment: U mean it eventually worked out?  Like 24 hours?

Comment: Yeah. It has happened to me a few times (when installing updates) and it was also something like 315/317. I just went away and cam back the next day, and it was done.

Answer (score 0):

> Installation of vs 2019 community stuck at 98%

It is quite a strange behavior and thanks to Adrian for sharing useful suggestion.

**First**, please try **Adrian's** suggestion and if you still face the same issue later, you can try my suggestion:

**Suggestion**

**1)** reboot your computer

**2)** disable `Windows Defender real time protection`.

**3)** run the `vs_community.exe` as **administrator** again and **note** that previously installed modules are recorded, so it will be skipped

**In addition**, if there are any updates to Windows, please update them.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this exact same issue but with VS2019 Enterprise and I tried all of these suggestions and nothing has worked so far. Stuck at 98% with Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Extra.Resources refusing to download and install